# How to Unit Test Repository Method That Takes Lambda Expression as A Parameter

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing

I have a repository method as follows:

```
 public ICollection<TEntity> Find(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> where)
 {
        return Set.Where(where).ToList();
 }
```

`Set` is an EntityFramework `DbSet<TEntity>`

What is the best approach to unit test this method? I can mock the `DbSet<TEntity>` to return some dummy data easily, but I'm not entirely sure of what constitutes a valid or worthwhile test for this method.

For example, I can test the return type is correct and that an empty collection is returned for a predicate that is clearly never going to be satisfied, but what other tests should I be running?

Should I just write a test that passes an expression that is always true to test true conditions and another test that passes an expression that is always false to test false conditions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you mock the `Set` there´s nothing more in the method which effectivly *can* be tested. The method then consists only of a mock and nothing more. If `Set`is just a mock a call to `Where` will also return any dummy data according to how you set your mock. So you´re actually testing that your mock was mocked the way you want instead of your method to do the right things with the data *retrieved* from that mock. Since what you do with this data is trivial (just calling `ToList` on it) there´s no need to do any testing here.

However you should consider that the actual `Expression` was built correctly, but you won´t do this within the test for that method but within the test for the *calling* code.